# How to determine which physical disk in a RAID needs to be replaced in the event of a failure?

Tags: raid, mdadm

If I have a RAID array configured (using `mdadm`), what's the best way of making sure I can tell which physical disk to replace in the event that one fails?

`cat /proc/mdstat` will tell me that (say) `/dev/sda` has failed. That's OK.

But when I look at the physical disks, which one is `/dev/sda`?

If I use `lshw -class disk`, I see it returns a logical name (eg `/dev/sda`) and a serial number. If that serial number corresponds to the number given on the disk casing, and the logical name doesn't change, I could write both somewhere visible on each disk.

However, I see that for some reason the serial number given by `lshw` is sometimes **not** the serial number given on the casing of the drive. I also suspect the logical name may change under some circumstances.

So is there a better way? Some script that can tell me which of the labelled disks to switch out, perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Physically Identify the failed hard drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/64239/physically-identify-the-failed-hard-drive)

Comment: Ah - yes, although the first answer doesn't work for me (will amend my question to explain why), the second using `ledctl` is best I think.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/799793/229501) recommending the use of the `ledmon` package seems to be the best one in my case.

The use of `ledctl locate=/dev/sdX` is a foolproof way of knowing which drive to remove - although I might still have to do this by process of elimination if `ledctl` could not see the failed drive (so, forcing a read/write operation on the drives in the hope I can spot the one that isn't flashing).